# How to convert dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss to offsetdatetime - java

Tags: java, datetimeoffset, localdate

I upgraded to:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime _date = org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.parse ("10/19/2020 18:00:47", dtf);
```

and get:
2020-10-19T18:00:47
but I still don't have an exit with the standard: 2020-10-19T18:00:47.868-03:00

Comment: Your input string is not in the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. There is no time in there. There is no timezone offset in there either. So all you have is a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previously accepted answer by user3197884 is correct and informative (+1). I didn’t feel it fully answered the question as asked, so I wanted to contribute the conversion into an `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    OffsetDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("10/19/2020 18:00:47", dtf)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"))
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is what you asked for:

> 2020-10-19T18:00:47-03:00

Since your string doesn’t have an offset or time zone in it, we need to provide the offset in some other way. Exactly which is the best way in your particular situation I dare not tell, but a very common good way is providing the time zone that was assumed for the string. I just picked one, please insert your own time zone instead.

Rather than swapping `10` and `19` in the string I have swapped `dd` and `MM` in the format pattern. Obviously either works.

Answer (score 1):

Your DateTimeFormatter has ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") but you have used "10/19/2020 18:00:47".
Month cannot be 19.

Change your input to "19/10/2020 18:00:47" and it should work.

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime _date = org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.parse("19/10/2020 18:00:47", dtf);
System.out.println(_date);
```